# Two regular dice are rolled. Given that one of them is a $6$, what is the probability that the other is also a $6$?

Tags: probability, dice, bayes-theorem

I'm having trouble with the following question for and I have an exam in two days:

> Two regular dice are rolled. Given that one of them is a $6$, what is the probability that the other is also a $6$? Given that the first is a $6$ what is the probability that the other is also a $6$? Contrast these two situations in terms of Bayes' theorem, with particular attention to the amount of information that is made available in each case.

I think the answer is just $1/6$ for both but I presume that's wrong and I am not sure how Bayes theorem helps as $P(\text{1st is a 6 given 2nd is a 6})$ is not much more helpful than $P(\text{2nd is a 6 given 1st is a 6})$ in this context.

Comment: The first one is $P((X_1=6|X_2=6)\cup (X_2=6|X_1=6))=P(X_1=6|X_2=6)+P(X_2=6|X_1=6)$ The second one is just $P(X_2=6|X_1=6)$ Thus the first one is not $1/6$.

Comment: @callculus so what are these probabilities equal to? is the P(X2=6|X1=6) equal to  1/6 and is P(X1=6|X2=6) equal to 1/6?

Comment: Yes, that´s right.

Comment: @callculus so I dont need to use bayes theorem even though the question asks to?

Comment: Maybe. I think you know how it looks like. But the following I do not really know what is supposed to do:" *...with particular attention to the amount of information that is made available in each case.* "

Comment: The conditional probabilities for $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not additive. The assumption in the first case is that you find out that at least one of the two dice is a $6$, that is, you want the probability $P(X_1\cap X_2\mid X_1\cup X_2)$, which is actually quite a bit less than $1/6$.

Comment: Isn't rolling two 6's independent of each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the value of the first die, and let $B$ be the value of the second die.

a) 
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Two sixes}|\text{One six})&=\frac{P(\text{Two sixes})}{P(A = 6\cup B = 6)}\\
&=\frac{(1/6)^2}{1/6+1/6-1/36}\\
&=\frac{1/36}{11/36}\\
&=\frac{1}{11}
\end{align*}

---

I think the other/more natural way to state this is
"Given at least one six, what is that chance that you got two sixes". Then this is
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Two sixes | At least one six})&=
\frac{P(\text{Two sixes})}{P(\text{At least one six})}\\
&=\frac{P(\text{Two sixes})}{1-P(\text{No sixes})}\\
&=\frac{(1/6)^2}{1-(5/6)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{11}
\end{align*}

---

You could also count.
$$(1,6),(2,6),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(6,6),(6,5),(6,4),(6,3),(6,2),(6,1)$$
Notice that there are $11$ equally likely outcomes. $1$ of them is desirable. Hence the chance is $1/11$.

---

b) They tell you the first is a six, hence
$$P(B=6|A=6) = \frac{P(A = 6, B=6)}{P(A = 6)} = \frac{(1/6)(1/6)}{(1/6)} = \frac{1}{6}$$
since the outcome of $A$ is independent of the outcome of $B$.

Comment: I think part A is asking for P(1st is a six | 2nd is a six) or  P(2nd is a six |1st is a six)

Comment: That's what I have (I think).

Comment: would that not equal 1/12 then?

Comment: I showed my work, which you should do also, in every post. I got $1/11$.

Comment: i see your workings but if you are saying that your answer is the same as P(1st is a six | 2nd is a six) or P(2nd is a six |1st is a six) should it not equal 1/12 as P(1st is a six | 2nd is a six) = 1/6 and P(2nd is a six |1st is a six) = 1/6, 1/6 +1/6 = 1/12 @probablyme

Comment: No, I am not saying my answer is equivalent to your statement. Your statement does not make sense.

Comment: @niallstudent I updated my answer. Consider giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Sorry the answer someone else gave confused me. That makes sense now, part a was strangely worded. Thanks!